# How to set up the current day (today) as a default date on FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery

Now the default date is 2017-12-12...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },


      defaultDate: '2017-12-12',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      businessHours: true, // display business hours
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can directly set today as default in this script

```
$("#calendar").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: this is not a datepicker, it's fullcalendar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

or

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: moment('2014-09-01'),
    ...
});
```